# Whats the difference between these two lines in PHP....Are they both variables?

Tags: php

There's:

```
$myvar="somthing";
```

and:

```
define('myvar', 'something');
```

I know the first one is defining a variable and I thought the second one was too, until someone told me its not...

Whats the difference between the two? They both do the same things right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one creates a **constant**.  Syntactically, it's a lot like a variable, except that it can't be varied.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php, or more generally http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php.

Comment: ahh! But cant you just use const something="somthing"; for that?